# Start graph rendering after left sided labels in Highstock

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In my highstock charts i required label on the left side of the graphs. When i used `opposite: false` + `align: left` for labels they are positioned above graph. But i want to start graph rendering after labels ends.
[Left side labels without required graph render](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/xaxis/opposite/)

I saw solution for my problem in Highcharts not in highstock some time before. But now i cant find it to show what exactly i need

Expected result

[image: Expected result]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand how the fiddle that you linked to does not do what you've stated you want. can you elaborate on what the problem is, and/or what it is you want?

Comment: Added an image of expected result

Comment: It could be achieved in a regular chart with minPadding - http://jsfiddle.net/761yct66/ In stockChart minPadding does not work because extremes are changed dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you want the labels inside the plot area.

You can do this by adding

```
labels: {
  align: 'left',
  x: 0
}
```

to your `yAxis` properties.

This moves the starting point of the labels to the axis line, and extends the labels to the right from that point. If you want them pushed further inside, just increase `x`.

The problem that you'll run into is that the plot will not respect the label placement - your line will still start at the same point, as if the labels weren't there.

Normally, you could just use the `minPadding` setting on the `xAxis` to increase the space for the labels, but this doesn't work in the case of the `navigator`, as explained here:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.minPadding

> When the axis' min option is set or a min extreme is set using axis.setExtremes(), the minPadding will be ignored

I am sure there is some work around for this problem, but I do not have the solution currently.

Updated fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/d6mre68v/